# jqgrid editable dropdown's width is set to a minimal value in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Hi I have a jqgrid with a popup for editing. A couple of the editable properties are editable by selects. This is an example of the code for one of the selects:

```
{ name: 'PaymentTypeLookupId', index: 'PaymentTypeLookupId', width: 150, align: 'center', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Invoice/GetPayments/',
                  buildSelect: function (data) {
                      var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                      var s = '<select>';

                      if (response.rows && response.rows.length) {
                          for (var i = 0, l = response.rows.length; i < l; i++) {
                              var ri = response.rows[i];
                              s += '<option value="' + ri.Id + '">' + ri.Name + '</option>';
                          }
                      }
                      return s + "</select>";
                  }
              }
```

This works fine in IE8 when it is set to compatibilty mode. However when not in compatibility mode the dropdown has a really small width set until you click on it to select an option and it sets itself to a good size:

[image]

The payment Type dropdown actually has items in it but until clicking on it the width is as shown.

Does anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: Which jqGrid version you use? The problem was in some old versions, but it should be fixed now.

Comment: 4.1.1 is this version too old?

Comment: just updated to 4.3.1 still the same

Comment: The version 4.1.1 was published Jun 19, 2011. I remind about the same or very close bug which was fixed. So first of all I would recommend you to test whether you can reproduce the same problem in current jqGrid 4.3.1. It is also 3 mount old, but the problem which you describe could be do fixed in the version 4.3.1.

Comment: You should prepare the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem or you can post URL which I could see online. Instead of server response to '/Invoice/GetPayments/' one can use just file with the same JSON content.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reproduce the problem which you described, but without any success. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew5.htm) where I used explicitly jqGrid 4.1.1 fill Form editing dialog without any problem.

You should prepare some demo which can be used to reproduce your problem. As a workaround you can set `width` of the select explicitly:

```
{ name: 'PaymentTypeLookupId', ...
    editoptions: {
        dataUrl: '/Invoice/GetPayments/',
        buildSelect: function (data) {
            ...
        },
        style: "width: 150px"
    }}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew5_.htm)